# How do I get a count of files in a folder in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

I would like to know how many files are in any given folder/directory/branch of a Perforce depot, but I don't see a way to do this.  The `p4 fstat` command was my first thought, but it doesn't appear to have options to return file counts.  Is there a simple way to get a count of files in a folder using either the graphical or command-line client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the `p4 fstat` doesn't offer a way to obtain file counts per se, you can easily parse its output to obtain this information.  Note, this works in Windows, but I would imagine it is easily modified for other OSes.  Here's how you do it:

```
p4 fstat -T depotFile //depot/some/folder/... | find /c "... depotFile"
```

It can also be done with the `p4 files` command as thusly:

```
p4 files //depot/some/folder/... | find /c "//"
```

Comment: Looks like you've figured it out. Note that if you don't want to include sub-folders, you should probably use '*', not '...', as '... includes sub-folders as well as files in the folder you named. Another command you might try would be 'p4 files'. But 'p4 fstat' is pretty good for your purpose, and it's quite fast and efficient. BTW, to what purpose is your query? That is, what decision will your tool make based on how many files are in a directory?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `p4 sizes -s` command.

```
C:\test>p4 sizes -s ...
... 5 files 342 bytes
```

or if you want just the count:

```
C:\test>p4 -F %fileCount% sizes -s ...
5
```

(obviously the file argument can be anything else in place of `...` which is the current directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
p4 files //depot/dir1/dir2/... | wc -l
```

Explanation:

1. `p4 files //depot/dir1/dir2/...` is the command that recursively prints the files under dir2 to screen.
2. Pipe that through wordcount lines (`| wc -l`) to count the number of output lines.

This works in Linux/Unix systems, and in Windows if you're using cygwin (or some other Linux-like terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Powershell method:

To count the files in a specific directory:

```
p4 files //depot/dir1/dir2/... | Measure-Object
```

Alternatively:

```
(p4 files //depot/dir1/dir2/...).Count
```

The following will give you a list of all child directories and their file counts in an object that you can view as a table, sort, export to csv, etc:

```
p4 dirs //depot/dir1/* | Select-Object -Property @{Name="Path";Expression={$PSItem}},@{Name="FileCounts";Expression={(p4 files $PSItem/...).Count}}
```